# KIbana connection and ES integration using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

This project basically involved Elasticsearch cloud and Kibana, and Python client as well. Currently, I am stuck trying to add an index pattern to Kibana from ES. I found some helpful functions by pybana such as "update_or_create_default_index_pattern" but nothing related to Kibana connection.

I would appreciate it if someone have ever worked with this tool using python (or whatever programming language)
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kibana index pattern API.

With the python `requests` package (or any other HTTP library), you can create an HTTP request for creating the index pattern.

[Create index pattern API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns-api-create.html#index-patterns-api-create)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Netanel, Even though if it's for Elastic Cloud?

Comment: Yes. you only need to provide an authorization key:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/api.html#api-authentication